# Money payment integration in swift 4.0

Tags: ios, swift, payment, swift4

My problem right now is how I can save the response after a successful payment. I have tried the following:

```
func transactionCompleted(withResponse response : NSDictionary,errorDescription error:NSError) -> Void {
     self.dismiss(animated: true){
        self.showAlertViewWithTitle(title: "Message", message: "congrats! Payment is Successful")
     }
}

func transactinFailed(withResponse response : NSDictionary,errorDescription error:NSError) -> Void {
      self.dismiss(animated: true){
          self.showAlertViewWithTitle(title: "Message", message: "Oops!!! Payment Failed"                    
      }
}
```

But it's been unable to call the following functions

```
 var restURL = URL(string: "https://test.payu.in/_payment")
    req = NSMutableURLRequest(url: restURL!, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 60.0)
    req.httpMethod = "POST"
    var hashValue = "\(KEY_TEST)|\(transactionId)|\(Amount)|\(productInfo)|\(firstName)|\(emailID)|\(udf1)|\(udf2)|\(udf3)|\(udf4)|\(udf5)||||||\(SALT_TEST)"


    let strPaymentHash = sha1(string: hashValue)




        post = "key=\("\(KEY_TEST)")&amount=\("\(Amount)")&productinfo=\("\(productInfo)")&firstname=\("\(firstName)")&email=\("\(emailID)")&udf1=\("\(udf1)")&udf2=\("\(udf2)")&udf3=\("\(udf3)")&udf4=\("\(udf4)")&udf5=\("\(udf5)")&surl=\("\(SURL)")&furl=\("\(FURL)")&phone=\("\(PHONE)")&hash=\("\(strPaymentHash)")&txnid=\("\(transactionId)")"
    print("Post",post)

    self.req.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")
    self.req.httpBody = post.data(using: .utf8)

    webView_guide.load(req as URLRequest)
```

}

Comment: Finally i have resolved the issue actually we can get response by providing them success url and failuar url by creating those url on our server and we can get the data from our server itself.

Comment: Hi,After implementing this have you selected encryption compilances option yes while submitting to the app store?

Answer (score 1):

I see that you call `self` inside a dismiss completion block and this is usually a bad practice.

The completion block is executed after the View Controller has been dismissed. This means your view is no longer on the screen. I think you want to render your alert view inside that view, which is not possible because it is off screen.

You can delegate the event from presented controller to the parent and handle it there using the delegate pattern.
Swift is delegate/protocol pattern oriented.

Create an interface for who will handle the response of the payment, something like:

```
protocol MyTransactionDelegate {
    func transactionDidFinish(completed: Bool, response: NSDictionary, error: NSError)
}
```

Add to **presentedViewController** a reference to **parentViewController**:

```
class PresentedViewController {
    weak myDelegate: MyTransactionDelegate?
}
```

Do **parentViewController** conform to `MyTransactionDelegate` protocol and when it presents **presentedViewController** set itself as its delegate.

The last things to do is change your methods to:

```
func transactionCompleted(withResponse response : NSDictionary,errorDescription error:NSError) -> Void {
    self.delegate?.transactionDidFinish(completed: true, response: response, error: error)
    self.dismiss(animated: true)
}

func transactionFailed(withResponse response : NSDictionary,errorDescription error:NSError) -> Void {
    self.delegate?.transactionDidFinish(completed: false, response: response, error: error)
    self.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: hi, actually payment getting successful on WKWebview only how to get that instance from wkwebview page after payment successfull from pay u money as i am loading that on wkwebview.